MacOS SwiftUI App not going through Photos Permissions Flow Properly
I'm building a MacOS SwiftUI app that needs to get access to the Photos library. I'm setting the value in the Info.plist:

As well as file access in the Sandbox settings:

struct PhotosPermissionView: View {
    @State private var authorizationStatus: PHAuthorizationStatus = .notDetermined
    @State private var logMessage: String = "Waiting for user action..."

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("Photos Permission")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()

            if authorizationStatus == .authorized || authorizationStatus == .limited {
                Text("Access to Photos Library granted!")
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                Text(logMessage)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                Button("Fetch Photos Library") {
                    fetchPhotosLibrary()
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            } else if authorizationStatus == .denied || authorizationStatus == .restricted {
                Text("Access to Photos Library denied.")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                Text("You can enable access in System Preferences.")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            } else {
                Text("Permission to access Photos is not yet determined.")
                    .foregroundColor(.orange)
                Button("Request Access") {
                    requestPhotosPermissionAndTriggerUI()
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            checkPhotosAuthorizationStatus()
        }
    }

    /// Check the current Photos authorization status
    private func checkPhotosAuthorizationStatus() {
        authorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus(for: .readWrite)
        logMessage = "Current Photos authorization status: \(authorizationStatus.rawValue)"
        print(logMessage)
    }

    /// Request Photos permission and trigger the UI by accessing the library
    private func requestPhotosPermissionAndTriggerUI() {
        print("Requesting Photos permission...")

        // Request authorization
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .readWrite) { status in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                authorizationStatus = status
                logMessage = "Authorization status after request: \(status.rawValue)"
                print(logMessage)

                if status == .authorized || status == .limited {
                    print("Access granted. Attempting to trigger Photos UI...")
                    self.fetchPhotosLibrary() // Trigger Photos Library access
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// Attempt to access the Photos Library to trigger system behavior
    private func fetchPhotosLibrary() {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 1
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
        logMessage = "Fetched \(fetchResult.count) assets from the Photos Library."
        print(logMessage)
    }
}

When I run the app, this is the status message I get:

In the System Preferences / Privacy and Security / Photos section, my app doesn't show up:

How do I modify my code so that my app will actually show up as an option to grant Photos permission in System Preferences.

DispatchQueue.main.async won't work in View struct cause they have no life time, theyre just simple values not objects
